# MAX or MIN on SQL table value with condition

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, max, min

Hi I was hoping someone could tell me a better way to do this, what I have works, but it is slow and is causing my query to run over 4 seconds.  The tables all have indexes on and I can't see anything in the execution plans in particular.

I want to get the min assessmentId where initial = 1, and also the max assessmentId altogether from my table.

Is there a better way that joining the table twice?

```
select
r.PatientId,
MAX(r.ReferralId),
MIN(a.AssessmentOneId),
MAX(a1.AssessmentOneId)
from dbo.Referral r
inner join dbo.Patient p on p.PatientId = r.PatientId
left join dbo.AssessmentOne a on a.ReferralId = r.ReferralId and a.Initial = 1
left join dbo.AssessmentOne a1 on a1.ReferralId = r.ReferralId
where
p.AccountId = @pAccountId
group by r.PatientId
```

I've also tried the following using sub queries, but I am still getting bad performance.

```
select
r.PatientId,
MAX(r.ReferralId),
(Select MIN(a.AssessmentOneId) from dbo.AssessmentOne a where a.ReferralId = MAX(r.ReferralId) and a.Initial = 1),
(Select MAX(a.AssessmentOneId) from dbo.AssessmentOne a where a.ReferralId = MAX(r.ReferralId))
from dbo.Referral r
inner join dbo.Patient p on p.PatientId = r.PatientId
where
p.AccountId = @pAccountId
group by r.PatientId
```

Any help you can give would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this query:

```
select r.PatientId, MAX(r.ReferralId), MIN(a.AssessmentOneId), 
       MAX(a1.AssessmentOneId)
from dbo.Referral r inner join
     dbo.Patient p
     on p.PatientId = r.PatientId left join
     dbo.AssessmentOne a
     on a.ReferralId = r.ReferralId left join
     dbo.AssessmentOne a1
     on a1.ReferralId = r.ReferralId
where p.AccountId = @pAccountId
group by r.PatientId;
```

I would recommend indexes on `Patient(AccountId, PatientId)`, `Referral(PatientId, ReferralId)`, and `AssessmentOne(ReferalId, Initial)`.

The double join is a bit strange.  So, I would write this as:

```
select p.PatientId, max(r.ReferralId), max(a.AssessmentOneId), 
       max(case when a.Initial = 1 then a.AssessmentOneId end)
from dbo.Referral r inner join
     dbo.Patient p
     on p.PatientId = r.PatientId left join
     dbo.AssessmentOne a
     on a.ReferralId = r.ReferralId 
where p.AccountId = @pAccountId
group by p.PatientId;
```

I doubt this really affects performance, but it seems simpler to me.

Comment: I think you want to take `Initial = 1` out of the join on the second query?

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. I will try this out thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't give a noticeable performance boost, but did make it cleaner.  I've accepted the answer.  I think I will have to store the calculated results in a separate table and update each patient when an assessment form is created and then just reference this table instead. Thanks again for your speedy reply.

Answer (score 1):

The referral table is a bridge table for the m:n relation of patient and assessment. As you want certain assessment IDs per patient, it's necessary to join the tables, what you are already doing. However, as we must look up all assessments per patient to get the maximum number, we can get the minimum initial assessment ID on-the-fly:

```
select
  p.patientid,
  max(r.referralid),
  min(case when initial = 1 then assessmentoneid end),
  max(assessmentoneid)
from dbo.patient p
join dbo.referral r on on r.patientid = p.patientid
left join dbo.assessmentone a on a.referralid = r.referralid
where p.accountid = @paccountid
group by p.patientid;
```

You'll want these indexes:

- patient (accountid, patientid)
- referral (patientid, referralid)
- assessmentone (referralid, assessmentoneid, initial)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is a great answer, the same as the one above and can only accept one so have gone with the one who answered first.  Unfortunately it didn't give a noticeable performance boost, but did make it cleaner.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that this didn't speed up the query. I was sure that the indexes would be used, and as they are covering indexes (i.e. containing all columns used in the query), they would certainly speed up the query. Maybe there are only few accounts, so the DBMS sees that in spite of reading one account only it would have to read a too big percentage of all data and decides to do this better without indexes.